# How to connect multiple IR Cameras with C# via usb

Tags: c#, camera, camera-calibration

**In context:**
At the moment I have a code example designed in C# for connecting a single camera Optris. The code work in windows form for one camera, I try to modify the code to work for two cameras, but the system always connects with the last cameras configuration.

[then the view of the modified example for two cameras where it shows the same image corresponding to the second camera.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL2VF.png)

**The modifications made**

The image that is displayed in the second picture box was duplicated from the example code with all the variables and methods, additionally all the duplicate variables of the code example was simply added the number two.

Additionally, added the original code and the code with the modification:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/Jhonalexama/OptrisTwoCamaras)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in the documentation (http://documentation.evocortex.com/libirimager2/html/classevo_1_1IRImager.html) and watching your code, seems that .dll uses a singleton pattern.

I tried to clone the dll and make two invokes, and works!

[Working with 2 cameras](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URVUv.png)

You have two options:

1. Clone the dll for every camara that you need to connect.
2. Try to find the "problem" or contact with the sdk programmers.

Regards!

Comment: That solution worked, but it would be a problem in the future to use one dll for each camera.
Thank you very much for your contribution.